# How do I retrieve Healthkit record data in the same format as in the Health app?

Tags: ios, healthkit

I am trying to look for the API which returns healthkit data in the same format as the health app's "All Recorded Data". I've attached an image below. We are currently using the HKStatisticsCollectionQuery but there are discrepancies. Instead I would like to you the exact step data format provided by Apple here. Thank you.

[All recorded data sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBhl7.jpg)